# How do I to create a bread crumbs navigation like this?

Tags: css

I'm trying to wrap my head around making a breadcrumbs navigation that will look sort of like this.

[image: image of bread crumbs with circles below labels with line through circles]

I want the circle to be centered beneath the text. I want the text to stay within the container where I place the breadscrumbs. E.g. I can't use position absolute to place them relatively to the circle, since they would potentially overflow the container I put them in.

This is where I'm currently at... https://jsfiddle.net/04pts9ey/2/

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.container {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 40px;
}

.page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.step {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.circle {
  background: purple;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.step:not(:last-child) .circle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <span class="step">
      <span class="text">Short</span>
      <span class="circle"></span>
    </span>

    <span class="step">
      <span class="text">Long title here</span>
      <span class="circle"></span>
    </span>

    <span class="step">
      <span class="text">Medium title</span>
      <span class="circle"></span>
    </span>

    <span class="step">
      <span class="text">Another title</span>
      <span class="circle"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="page"></div>
</div>
```

My main issue seems to be that I can't align the circle and text together, since putting them in a div together, makes it hard for me to draw the lines between the circles.

Comment: Put your <span class="text">Short</span> inside <span class="circle"></span>
and use position: relative and transform: translate() to center it

Comment: I'm not really sure what exactly you mean. If I place the text span inside my circle span, The text will be displayed on the circle, as that is created using a simple block with width, height, background color and border radius.

Comment: Yes but you can move your elements outside of the circle by using position: relative
and transform: translate.
And because element will be inside the circle it would be easy for you to center them

Answer (score 3):

Something like this ?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.step {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.circle {
  background: orange;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.step:not(:last-child)>.circle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  background: orange;
}


/* Styles below are not needed, Used for illustration */

.wrapper {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<h3>Bottom right corner to resize for responsiveness</h3>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="step">
      <span class="text">Short</span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  </span>

  <span class="step">
      <span class="text">Long title here</span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  </span>

  <span class="step">
      <span class="text">Medium title</span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  </span>

  <span class="step">
      <span class="text">Another title</span>
  <span class="circle"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

---

The code is self explanatory nevertheless if you have any question please leave a comment, The only significant changes i made are:

1. moved the lines from being relative to `.circle` to `.step` to have more control over the width.
2. `margin-top:auto` on the `.circle` to ensure it's always on be bottom in case text overflows.
3. Made `.step` equal width using `flex: 1 1 0;` So the lines between the circle have a unified offset.

Comment: This is definetely a worthy answer. It's pretty smart using the width of the containers for the line between the dots. I would however have liked it to fill the entire container. When each elemet has flex one and is centered, it leaves white-space at the start and end of the breadcrumbs, but seems like it isn't such a trivial thing to fix. Also didn't know about the resize property, seems neat.

Comment: resize property is just for demonstrating changes in width it's not needed, Also can you explain further the issue with white-space you mentioned ?

Comment: What I mean is that I want the content of the first and last step to go up against the border. I highlighted the area that I want to have removed if that makes more sense. https://imgur.com/a/4uC1d5R

Comment: That space is going to be consumed as the `.wrapper` changes in width, Also that space is what we're relying on to create even width lines, If you want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/1fxq3a2s/ You'll have to manage the responsiveness